# How to plot a 2-D cone in python (matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm considerably new to python and making a map of a room. I've plotted the room, obstacles etc. And some points (which are sensors). Now I want make a 2-D cone which shows the area in which sensors see. I will have an angle and radius for the cone.
I've tried searching but mostly 3-D cones have been discussed here in previous questions. [How the cone should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8swTG.png)

Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patches=[]
ax.axis('equal')
we = Wedge((2756.6747,5339751.8148),10,30,180,edgecolor='b',facecolor='none')
patches.append(we)

ax.add_artist(we)
ax.set(xlim=[2740, 2800], ylim=[5339740, 5339780])

plt.show()
```

thanks to the direction given by @reedinationer

Answer (score 2):

You would use [matplotlib.patches.Wedge](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Wedge.html#matplotlib.patches.Wedge) such as [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-artist-reference-py). Another example that I've reduced to the more relevant bits is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

patches = []

wedge = mpatches.Wedge((.5, .5), 0.5, 30, 270, ec="none")
patches.append(wedge)

colors = np.linspace(0, 1, len(patches))
collection = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.cm.hsv, alpha=0.3)
collection.set_array(np.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(collection)

plt.show()
```

Which produces something like:

[image: Wedge plot]

Obviously you will need to tweak the `theta1` and `theta2` from their `30` and `270` to fit whatever angle you are trying to represent, and move the origin to wherever the sensors are located. Additionally you may want to color them all the same, instead of a rainbow but I'll let you figure out the details XD

Comment: thank you for directing me to matplotlib.patches
I used a slightly different method in which I understood methods to change colors, outlines etc.

Comment: Related solution that worked better for me 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295589/how-to-draw-a-colored-sector-using-python